# hibernate jpa unit tests autodection does not work

Tags: jpa

I have the following in persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.merc.model.log.EventLogging</class>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
        <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

If I comment out com.merc.model.log.EventLogging, I get Unknown entity exception.

Any ideas as to why autodetection would not work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be caused by the fact that by default autodetection works for classes inside the same classpath item where `persistence.xml` is located.

So, you have separate target folders for the code itself and for the tests (for example, if you use Maven with default configuration), and if this `persistence.xml` ends up in tests' target folder after compilation, classes from the main target folder wouldn't be detected.

You can use `<jar-file>` elements to point to other classpath items that should be searched for entities.

If you use Maven, you can do it in elegant way using resource filtering:

`persistence.xml`:

```
<jar-file>${project.build.outputDirectory}</jar-file>
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

Comment: I tried what you mentioned, but now i get the following error. I am using maven and trying to run a unit test -  Cannot parse persistence unit from URL [file:/media/01CB9CAC704E03A0/Projects/spring/hibernate/genericdao/target/test-classes/META-INF/persistence.xml]

Comment: @user373201: Check how this `persistence.xml` looks after compilation, have Maven resolved the placeholder?

Comment: yes. after build the the ${} is replaced by /media/01CB9CAC704E03A0/Projects/spring/hibernate/genericdao/target/classes. which is the value of project.build.outputDirectory. but my persistence.xml is in genericdao/target/test-classes/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: @user373201: And it still doesn't work? Everything looks fine, almost the same config works fine for me. Make sure `<jar-file>` is a child of `<persistence-unit>`.

Comment: I had to add a `file:///` prefix like so: `<jar-file>file:///${project.build.outputDirectory}</jar-file>` to fix a malformed URI exception.